# How can we get last run status of a Jenkins pipeline and, if it was failed then re-start it?

Tags: python, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, cloudbees

I have Scheduled pipeline that runs everyday at 6 AM, I want that pipeline to get executed at any cost.

I want some automated solution to check the pipeline execution status and, it should get **restarted** only if it got **failed** because of some reason.

I want automated solution, no manual/UI intervension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Naginator plugin in Jenkins to setup a post build action step that reschedules or restarts your job/pipeline upon status such as unstable or failure.

[Jenkins Plugin Naginator](https://plugins.jenkins.io/naginator/#:%7E:text=Simply%20install%20the%20plugin%2C%20and,to%20retry%20running%20the%20job.)

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to make curl to that job is successful or not with this sh command:

```
  final String BuildJobStatus= sh(script:"curl -X GET http://your user name:your credential@the jenkins server address/jenkins/job/jobName/lastBuild/api/xml?depth=0 | grep -Po '(?<=<${result}>).*?(?=</${result}>)'| head -1",returnStdout:true).trim()
```

then you should check **BuildJobStatus** If is Success  with another curl you can start your favourite job.